# How to find norm of the operator $Ax(t) = \cos (t)x(t)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization

Please explain me how can I get norm of this operator: $Ax(t)=\cos(t)x(t)$ where $A\colon C[-\pi/2,\pi/2] \to C[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. Thanks

Comment: Is $P$ supposed to be $\pi$?

Comment: Yes it is π. I am sorry

Comment: Which norm are you looking for?  Is this the $L^2$ norm?  Some other $L^p$ norm?  What are your thoughts on the problem?  Have you tried starting from the definition of the norm of an operator?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom it's C[a,b] norm, ||x|| = max x(t) where t belongs to interval [a,b]. Yes I have tried, but I can't find the solution

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you mean the $L^\infty \to L^\infty$ operator norm (i.e. the "sup-norm").  So, note that for $t \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, we may write
$$
\left| \cos(t)\,x(t) \right| \leq
\|\cos(\cdot)\|_{\sup} \cdot \|x\|_\sup
$$
Now, apply the definition.

Comment: I am sorry, but I'm not sure that it's L^infinity, I mean space C[a, b] of all continuous functions on [a, b] with the sup norm.

Comment: Applying the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm to the continuous functions gives you the sup-norm.  All you really need to know here is that $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ is *my* notation for the sup-norm.

Comment: See my edit.${}$

Comment: Ok thank you, but I can't understand the process of receiving your inequality

Comment: Try to understand it then.  Do you believe the inequality?  If not, try to come up with a counterexample.

Comment: is it Cauchy–Schwarz inequality? if yes, how you received ∣cos(t)x(t)∣∣ from integral?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19593/discussion-between-user3378283-and-omnomnomnom).

Comment: What integral?${}$